# Ошибка NPM «Не удается найти исполняемый файл Python»

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/jowissa/ma/layout_product-cards/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.19.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/jowissa/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/jowissa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node" "/Users/jowissa/ma/layout_product-cards/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jowissa/ma/layout_product-cards/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jowissa/.npm/_logs/2022-05-16T13_33_15_037Z-debug-0.log
```

Делаю npm i, выпадает ошибка связанная с python. При етом сам пайтон установлен, на других проектах все работает нормально. Что ето может быть?

Comment: какая у вас версия ноды?

Comment: По дефолту используется v14.19.1

Comment: node sass в пакетах есть?

Comment: сейчас проверил, нету

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, список пакетов, которые вы хотите установить

Comment: `/Users/jowissa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/lib
├── @mate-academy/scripts@1.2.3
├── corepack@0.10.0
├── node-gyp@9.0.0
├── npm@8.10.0
└── product-cards@1.0.0 -> ./../../../../../ma/layout_product-cards`

Comment: в package.json, в dependencies и в devDependencies(если есть), какие пакеты?
Вот, к примеру
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0"
  },

Comment: Проверьте из какой папки вы запускаете (cd) "npm i", Возможно вы находить в другой папке